# Can I develop for WIndows Phone 8.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-server

I am using a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine for general windows development (SharePoint among other things, hence the server edition).

I have received a project from a client that I need to debug, and it is a Windows Phone 8.1 project developed on Windows 8.1 - can I "convert" this project or develop on it in it's current form on this virtual machine?

When I open the solution, the project itself just says "Windows 8.1 required", and I would prefer not having to set up another VM with Windows 8.1, Visual Studio, etc. again just for this specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The project already says that 8.1 is required.  WS2008 doesn't have the bits it needs to render the Phone app.